# Stored procedure with large number of parameters

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, sqldatatypes

I have a table with more than 50 columns and it is already normalized. Most number of columns have data type as nvarchar.

Now, I need to write a stored procedure that inserts a record in the same table.

I have not sure whether 
1) I should write a SP with 50 parameters or 
2) I should write SP that takes Xml as a parameter and extract record to be inserted into table as mentioned here.

[How to insert xml data into table in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758992/how-to-insert-xml-data-into-table-in-sql-server-2005)

Please advise in terms of performance. Thanks.

Comment: you really need to pass all 50 parameters to proc? If you need to unambiguously identify table row - use primary key / unique column value instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx , you can have up to 2100 parameters. So this won't be a problem.

**In term of performance, it'll take extra processing to extract each node from the XML**, but it certainly gives more flexibility (and readability) if you'd like to produce dynamics inserts (even if it could be done with standard parameters, with a bit more work I guess).

Comment: thanks @Thomas
Is there a better way to extract details from XML? For eg. using temporary table

Comment: Using the SQL Server XML object is the way to do it, I don't see any reason to parse it yourself. It'll take extra processing either way, but for single calls it won't be a problem I guess