# Insert multiple rows into SQL Server 2005 using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC / C# application.

I have a list of objects lets say `List<Student>` students that were imported from a CSV.

I want to insert them into a SQL Server 2005 database using stored procedures and transactions. In case a row fails it should rollback.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nice - so go ahead and write some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use ADO or Entity?

You can use transactions from your code.
For ADO

```
try
{
    sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

    //call insert in loop

    sqlTransaction.Commit();
}
catch{
    sqlTransaction.Rollback();
}
```

For Entity

```
try
{
    entityTransaction = Context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

    //call insert in loop

    entityTransaction.Commit();
}
catch{
    entityTransaction.Rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

1. Bulk insert using Bulk Insert command (from files to DB)

Please check this

[How to insert xml data into table in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758992/how-to-insert-xml-data-into-table-in-sql-server-2005)

2. You can generate XML and then insert.

Please check this

[How to insert xml data into table in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758992/how-to-insert-xml-data-into-table-in-sql-server-2005)

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: To insert list to database, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426300/how-to-insert-list-from-c-sharp-into-sql-server-2008